# Does Heroku standalone PostgreSQL available on Asia(Tokyo/Singapore) region?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, availability-zone

I am building a service, and considering using of Heroku standalone PostgreSQL. Anyway I need to deploy the service to the Asian area (Tokyo/Singapore replicated), and I saw PostgreSQL is available only on US/EU region for Heroku dynos.

I want to know whether the standalone PostgreSQL is also available only on those regions or also available on Tokyo/Singapore regions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Heroku Postgres (in fact any of Heroku) is only available in US and EU regions presently.